# WebSocket java plugin unable to connect

Tags: c#, android, websocket

I am using this http://anismiles.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/websocket-support-in-android%E2%80%99s-phonegap-apps/#comment-689 plugin. I am experiencing a problem where when I create the websocket object and a regular tcp server written in c#. I confirm the the connection headers are recieved, however, the onopen or onmessage events in the javascript are not fired? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention using a regular tcp server.  Are you aware that a websocket connection is slightly more complicated that a regular tcp connection?  You have to complete a handshake then frame all subsequent messages.  Your browser handles all this for you on the client; you have to provide equivalent code on the server.

[RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) describes the protocol if you want to write your own server.  Or you could use an existing C# server - using either the [.NET v4.5 class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.aspx) or a [third party server](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response simonc. No, I was not aware and am checking into the .net v4.5 class.